# SSIS Combining multiple rows into a single row with multiple columns

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a table that does not have a primary key, but has an ID field that could be used as a primary key.  I would like to transform this table into something useable to track inserts, updates, and deletes. Just adding a Identity column is not a viable solution because the table gets recreated every evening.

The table looks something like:

```
ID       Specialty  
--       ---------  
01       Fam Med  
02       Fam Med  
02       Int Med  
03       Surgery  
03       Thor Sur  
03       Card Sur  
04       Undersea
```

I would like to transform it into something like the following and use ID as the primary key:

```
ID    Specialty1    Specialty2   Specialty3
--    ----------    ----------   ----------
01    Fam Med
02    Fam Med       Int Med
03    Surgery       Thor Sur     Card Sur
04    Undersea
```

I was leaning toward using the SQL pivot operator, but I am not familiar enough with pivots and I am not sure it is appropriate in this case.

Thank you in advance for your input.

Comment: You need 3 input columns to be able to do this particular pivot.  Are you missing a column?

Comment: @RajMore There is no other column and I cannot add one to this particular table.  I guess pivot is out as an option then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you would need to do the PIVOT is:

```
SELECT  ID,
        Specialty1,
        Specialty2,
        Specialty3
FROM    (   SELECT  ID, 
                    Specialty, 
                    SpecialtyNum = 'Specialty' + 
                                    CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID 
                                                        ORDER BY Specialty) AS VARCHAR(10))
            FROM    T
        ) AS t
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Specialty)
            FOR SpecialtyNum IN ([Specialty1], [Specialty2], [Specialty3])
        ) AS pvt;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f07a/1)**

The key is adding a further column that you can pivot on, so the result of the subquery:

```
SELECT  ID, 
        Specialty, 
        SpecialtyNum = 'Specialty' + 
                        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID 
                                            ORDER BY Specialty) AS VARCHAR(10))
FROM    T;
```

Gives you:

```
ID       Specialty  SpecialtyNum
--       ---------  -------------
01       Fam Med    Specialty1
02       Fam Med    Specialty1
02       Int Med    Specialty2
03       Surgery    Specialty1
03       Thor Sur   Specialty2
03       Card Sur   Specialty3
04       Undersea   Specialty1
```

Then you can pivot on the `SpecialtyNum` column. Since each value of specialtyNum is unique to an ID, there is no data loss through aggregation.

But with an unknown number of specialities you would need to generate this dynamically:

```
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
        STUFF(( SELECT  DISTINCT ',[Specialty' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Specialty) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] '
                FROM    T
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
            'SELECT ID, ' + @Cols  + 
            'FROM   (   SELECT  ID, 
                                Specialty, 
                                SpecialtyNum = ''Specialty'' + 
                                                CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID 
                                                                    ORDER BY Specialty) AS VARCHAR(10))
                        FROM    T
                    ) AS t
                    PIVOT
                    (   MAX(Specialty)
                        FOR SpecialtyNum IN (' + @Cols + ')
                    ) AS pvt;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f07a/2)**

Comment: Thank you, I learned something new today.  The dynamic code is something I can adapt to do exactly what I need.  Now to study up on using unpivot with dynamically created columns.